# Installing wifi driver on late macbook 2011 with ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, 12.10, macbook-pro

I followed the directions on [Installing Ubuntu 12.10 on Macbook Pro Retina (10,1)](http://cberner.com/2012/10/19/installing-ubuntu-12-10-on-macbook-pro-retina/)

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
wget http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
tar -xf broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
sudo reboot
```

When i try to do step three I get:

```
tar: broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Even though I downloaded the file thrice in Firefox and even extracted it in the archive manager. I’m new to Linux but its going to be hard to learn something if I cant even connect to wi-fi. Please help.

Comment: Why does an obsolete question suddenly pop up out of the blue?

Answer (score 0):

It switches should be

```
tar -jxvf broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
```